# Not wanted space before marginpar

Tags: spacing, positioning, marginpar

At the moment I'm working on a little report. Therefore I had to redefine the `\marginpar{}` command new because I wanted it in a smaller font-size compared to the 'normal text'. The code I've written is the following one:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mparhack}    
\usepackage{calc}    

\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}

\makeatletter

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\oldmarginpar[\color{black}\scriptsize #1]%
{\color{black}\scriptsize #1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello everybody!}

... but anyway, it's interesting. \marginpar{I don't know why there's some space ... ?}

\end{document}
```

Now, there's an image to show the appearing problem:
[image: Problem with vertical space]

I don't know why, but after my redefinition, there's some vertical space before the margin par added. It does no longer start at the same line like the 'normal text'.

So my question is, how can I redefine the `\marginpar` in that way that it will always start at the 'upper line' of the 'normal text'. In the image given above I want the `\marginpar`-text to appear on the blue line - the 'normal text' and the `\marginpar`-text should use the same first 'upper line'. (Unfortunately I don't know the exact typographic names for the things I described here, but I hope, you can help me and understand what I mean ...)

Thanks in advance,
  eniem

Comment: Try `\leavevmode` before the `\color` command.

Comment: @daleif Thank you! That works fine!
But, is there a possibility also to lift the `\marginpar`-Text up to the 'upper line' of the 'normal-text'?

Comment: @eniem, I only fixed your markup. See Stephans comment or Harish's answer.

Comment: @daleif ah. I see ... so, @Stephan Lehmke Thank you! That works fine! But, is there a possibility also to lift the `\marginpar`-Text up to the 'upper line' of the 'normal-text'?

Comment: @eniem This might be possible, but I advise strongly against it. In all typography, the *base line* (i.e. the line on which the letters "stand"; the red line in your image) is the point of vertical alignment. So the correct alignment looks like the image by Harish.

Comment: @StephanLehmke ah, ok I see! But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `\textcolor` instead of `\color`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}

\makeatletter

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\oldmarginpar[\textcolor{black}{\scriptsize #1}]%
{\textcolor{black}{\scriptsize #1}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello everybody!}

... but anyway, it's interesting. \marginpar{I don't know why there's some space ... ?}

\end{document}
```

[image]